# mod_rewrite rule for file to be downloaded from another directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Note: I couldn't find any similar question. Please let me know if duplicate question exists. I don't want to put duplicate question intentionally.

I have directory structure longer which I don't want users to find out as well as I want download file URL to be fancy.

My directory structure is

**Actual File Path =** `./my_dir/files/upload/user_images/user_file.pdf`

My Domain is having `./my_die/` as Document Root so `example.com` will serve contents of `./my_dir/`

To download file I have `http://example.com/files/upload/user_files/user_file.pdf`

Which I want to convert to

`http://example.com/user/uploads/user_file.pdf`

So I need MOD Rewrite Rule to convert as following:

`http://example.com/files/upload/user_files/user_file.pdf` to `http://example.com/user/uploads/user_file.pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rewrite rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/uploads/(.+)$ files/upload/user_files/$1 [L,NC]
```